# Using prompt to determine which function to use

Tags: python, function, prompt

The main function called two functions defined previously: "reg()" and "usa()"
I want the user to be able to decide which function to run.
However, even if "1" is selected, "usa()" still runs.

```
def main():
    prompt = (input("If you would like to change the regional market numbers,
                     press 1."
                    "If you would like to change the national market, press 2."))
    if prompt == 1:
        a = reg()
        a
    else:
        b = usa()
        b


main()
```

Comment: Which version of python do you use?\

Comment: `prompt` is always `str` in Py3k, comparing it to `int` will give you `False` all the time

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3 then `input()` will return a string, which when compared to an integer will always return false. There is no need to use if and else statements to decide which function to use:

```
def main():
    functions = {1: reg, 2: usa}
    prompt_message = 'If you would like to change the regional market numbers, press 1.\nIf you would like to change the national market, press 2.'
    prompt = str(input(message))
    function = functions[prompt]
```